# Writing a date range in access query

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm hoping to write a query in access that will show the week date range from Sunday to Saturday.
For instance, this week's would be formatted like: 10/15/17 - 10/21/17

Not sure how to even begin with this.

I do have a column of the Week Number using the formula: DatePart("ww",[date]).

It seems logical to write something that says

`if week number is the same, minimum date & " - "& maximum date`

I have no idea how to write this in a query though or if this would be to use VBA...

Here is essentially how the table looks. Column C is how I would like the query data to look once the query runs:

```
| Date    | Week | Date Range        |
|---------|------|-------------------|
| 8/1/17  | 1    | 8/1/17 - 8/7/17   |
| 8/4/17  | 1    | 8/1/17 - 8/7/17   |
| 8/7/17  | 1    | 8/1/17 - 8/7/17   |
| 8/8/17  | 2    | 8/8/17 - 8/14/17  |
| 8/11/17 | 2    | 8/8/17 - 8/14/17  |
| 8/14/17 | 2    | 8/8/17 - 8/14/17  |
| 8/15/17 | 3    | 8/15/17 - 8/21/17 |
| 8/18/17 | 3    | 8/15/17 - 8/21/17 |
| 8/21/17 | 3    | 8/15/17 - 8/21/17 |
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Well, you could at least start with providing sample data and expected output, so we can actually see things like how your table is structured, what you expect to happen if week number is not the same, etc.

Comment: A query *against what data* ?

Comment: You can find an answer here: [How to Find the First and Last Day in a Given Week, Month, or Year in Access 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh134613%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Ok, I added in some sample data. If the week number is NOT the same, the date range should move forward. For instance as the week number switches from 1 to 2, the date range moves to the next week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `WEEKDAY` which will tell you the day number of the week that your date falls on.  A quick calculation will return Sundays date - add 7 and you get the following Saturday date.

```
SELECT MyDate-Weekday(MyDate,1)+1 & " - " & MyDate-Weekday(MyDate,1)+7
FROM Table1
```